# Lifecycle of a widget provider

Tags: android

I am having hard time finding documentation on this. For the provider of an android widget, what is the life cycle of that particular provider object? 
I noticed that if I start off a async test then look for the object at a later time, it's gone. 
(by observation I can call onUpdate from onReceive, and I can tell the received will be alive until onUpdate is done)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AppWidgetProvider` is a `BroadcatReceiver`.You can find useful information in about  BroadcatReceive and so AppWidgetProvider.[Google Docs](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDQQFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html&ei=4BlVUYSXI82Z0AXJ34DgAQ&usg=AFQjCNH03p-pz2dqqdiGMIA_Twr7g7fwxg&sig2=HBBZd2h3eH4cc6Hug7_7tw&bvm=bv.44442042,d.d2k) say:

> A BroadcastReceiver object is only valid for the duration of the call
>   to onReceive(Context, Intent). Once your code returns from this
>   function, the system considers the object to be finished and no longer
>   active.
>
> This has important repercussions to what you can do in an
>   onReceive(Context, Intent) implementation: anything that requires
>   asynchronous operation is not available, because you will need to
>   return from the function to handle the asynchronous operation, but at
>   that point the BroadcastReceiver is no longer active and thus the
>   system is free to kill its process before the asynchronous operation
>   completes.
>
> In particular, you may not show a dialog or bind to a service from
>   within a BroadcastReceiver. For the former, you should instead use the
>   NotificationManager API. For the latter, you can use
>   Context.startService() to send a command to the service.

Also look [this web page](http://www.cinterviews.com/2009/11/broadcast-receiver-lifecycle-in-android.html).